# Do need a comma before "whose"?

Tags: commas, whose

Do I need a comma before "whose" in this sentence:

> John was a wonderful son, brother, uncle and friend whose charming personality made a mark on everyone who met him.

Comment: The sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why yes you do, two words back from it to be precise.

Comment: If in doubt make it 2 sentences, breaking after friend. Then "His charming ...".

Comment: Thanks for comments but I need to keep it one sentence, and what I'm really asking is: Do I need a comma between "friend" and "whose?"

Comment: I don't think it's required, but it can be helpful in avoiding the ambiguity that the relative clause applies to "friend" rather than "John".

Answer (score 1):

This should presumably be a supplementary ("non-restrictive") relative clause, so you would use a comma there, as well as one before "and":

> John was a wonderful son, brother, uncle, and friend, whose charming personality made a mark on everyone who met him.

Comment: I think it would be taken as non-defining even without the comma (which I'd drop because of comma clutter on most days). The rule is not absolute. // To force modification solely onto 'friend' I'd use '... and uncle, and a friend whose ...'.